# MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, samsung-galaxy

The Android MediaPlayer supports setting the data source with included HTTP Headers:
setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri, Map headers)

However if I use it to set HttpHeaders like this:

```
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("cookie", "rapidsession="+MyApplication.getInstance().getAccess_token());
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, mUri, headers )
```

It never play video on the phone:
Galaxy S6 edge,android6.0.1

but play normally on the phone like xiaomi

it can got the uri  and  i have added the Internet permission

when I play audio, it is working. But logcat says:

> 10-19 16:45:24.145 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>   10-19 16:45:24.415 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://video.zfwx.com/111/16mp4/qiyefengxian/20160923wuhua/1.m4a?key=40a3a0ec95632f538e53b530fb02f869&start=1
>   10-19 16:45:36.885 20369-21917/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 3477123 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
>   10-19 16:45:36.895 20369-20386/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (10973, 0)
>   10-19 16:45:40.005 20369-20386/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)

when I start the video, it is not working. The logcat says:

> 10-19 16:45:43.235 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://video.zfwx.com/111/16mp4/qiyefengxian/20160923wuhua/1.mp4?key=40a3a0ec95632f538e53b530fb02f869&start=3
>   10-19 16:45:51.275 20369-22248/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 15539690 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
>   10-19 16:45:51.405 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaPlayer: this is IMEDIA_PLAYER_VIDEO_EXIST
>   10-19 16:45:51.965 20369-21917/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 107713 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
>   10-19 16:45:52.295 20369-20387/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 56404 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
>   10-19 16:45:52.695 20369-21917/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 263623 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
>   10-19 16:45:53.055 20369-20862/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 107713 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
>   10-19 16:45:53.065 20369-22248/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
>   10-19 16:45:53.075 20369-22248/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
>   10-19 16:45:53.075 20369-22248/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
>   10-19 16:45:53.085 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: called in state MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR
>   10-19 16:45:53.085 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: called in state MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR
>   10-19 16:45:53.085 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: called in state MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR
>   10-19 16:45:53.085 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: called in state MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR
>   10-19 16:45:53.085 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: called in state MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR
>   10-19 16:45:53.085 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: isPlaying: called in state MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR
>   10-19 16:45:53.085 20369-20369/com.dj.zfwx.client.activity E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)

please help me to solve it,please...
luck to you
thanks again!

Comment: Lots of code is missing (before you will get help)!  Make sure you have event handlers hooked up, because errors WILL occur and you are calling stuff on `MediaPlayer` without it being in correct state.  There is buffering involved (esp. with video); it could be as simple as media is not "ready" before you try to play it.  It also looks like protocol errors at network level see `MediaHTTPConnection` messages.